# Spring boot problemas al obtener datos + Retrofit2

Tags: java, android-studio, spring-boot, retrofit

Hola soy nuevo con Spring Boot, Tengo el siguiente problema mi api me responde con los datos pero a la hora de tomarlos en la aplicación de java obtengo error.  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el error que me aparece , según entiendo no debería ya que tengo el mismo objeto en Spring boot como en mi aplicación para recibir la data.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi model de Springboot y JavaApp

```
    private Long interfaceTransactionId;
    private Long lineNum;
    private String segment1;
    private String creationDate;

    public TransactionsDto() {}

    public Long getInterfaceTransactionId() {
        return interfaceTransactionId;
    }

    public void setInterfaceTransactionId(Long interfaceTransactionId) {
        this.interfaceTransactionId = interfaceTransactionId;
    }

    public Long getLineNum() {
        return lineNum;
    }

    public void setLineNum(Long lineNum) {
        this.lineNum = lineNum;
    }

    public String getSegment1() {
        return segment1;
    }

    public void setSegment1(String segment1) {
        this.segment1 = segment1;
    }

    public String getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(String creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }
}
```

Mi código en la aplicación de java cuando consulto los datos.

```
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<TransactionsDto>> call, Response<List<TransactionsDto>> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Code  " + response.code());
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Body " + response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<TransactionsDto>> call, Throwable t) {

                showError("Error de Conexion"+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Mi Interface de javaApp

```
    @GET("TransactionsDto/getAllTransaction/{shipment_number}")
    Call<List<TransactionsDto>> getAllTransaction(@Path("shipment_number") Long shipment_number) ;

    @GET("TransactionsDto/getAll")
    Call<List<TransactionsDto>>getAll();}
```

Comment: Bueno, el error está claro. El programa espera una `List<TransactionsDto>`. Es decir, algo cómo: `[{"interfaceTransactionId":1, "segment1": "Segment"...}, {"interfaceTransactionId":2, "segment1": "Segment"...}]`, pero en cambio lo que está obteniendo es una lista de listas, no una lista de `TransactionsDto`.